# How to run an electric motor at constant current?

Tags: control, brushless-dc-motor, constant-current

How can an electric motor, specifically a Brushless DC motor, with constant current rather than constant voltage? With the aim of having a constant torque rather than a constant voltage.

Edit: The motor will have a, more or less, constantly dynamic loading.

Comment: One word answer: Feedback. Sense the current, and vary PWM duty cycle to hit your target current. Of course you have to commutate at the right time also.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer- use current control. A longer answer- you have to learn how to drive a brushless motor, this is not trivial.

The common system is like that:

MCU (firmware that runs position control on top of velocity control on top of current control) creates voltage (by changing PWM duty cycle on the three phases of the motor). The feedbacks are: current from two phases, position from encoder or hall effect sensors.

The voltage command from MCU must be calculated according to current loop requirements and motor position, to take into account the motor commutation.

I know, all that sounds gibberish, but it's only because the matter itself requires many many more details to know. In the end, driving a motor with constant current is really a trivial task.

Another thing i would suggest to think about, is what will happen with constant torque. I mean, at first the motor will accelerate, at the end, if you don't have load to compensate, the torque will be zero, because the voltage will be saturated and speed will be at it's maximum.

Comment: Correct. You have to limit the drive to the motor at the two extremes, to protect it. Limit the drive current to the motor's maximum rated current. And limit its speed (~ voltage) to its maximum safe speed. So you need a circuit that monitors both the motor's current and speed. Some motors have a "tach" output (tachometer), for sensing the speed.

Comment: So basically the MCU sample X number of times per revolution, calculates the position with Hall effect sensors, current with shunts(?), and compares that against the desired input then modifies the PWM to reach desired output?

Comment: Kind of. Normally it samples everything once per, say, 100 microseconds and adjusts the PWM accordingly each cycle. PWM is usually around 10kHz.